# How to capture the keywords in raw data and change the keywords?

Tags: powerbuilder

When I use PostURL function to post the blob data, And I have the variable to get the response text, but I have some pronblem, the raw data has something wrong
For example:

```
[{"status":"U","a":"","b":"","complete":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","link":"https:\/\/abc.efgh.com\/test?area=100&ref=5ERF2221","count":0}]
```

You will see link column's value has wrong I want to change it to

```
https://abc.efgh.com/test?area=100&ref=5ERF2221"
```

The correct result

```
[{"status":"U","a":"","b":"","complete":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","link":"https://abc.efgh.com/test?area=100&ref=5ERF2221","count":0}]
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your response string looks like JSON.  However, escaping the slashes within the double quote would make it invalid per the JSON specification.  The creator of your API should really correct the response to be proper JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function to replace by searching for `"\/"` and changing it to `"/"`.
Here is an example of how to use the powerbuilder function:

[Replace PowerScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44374677/5479161)